# I/O in NASM programs in Windows 7

Tags: nasm

I want to program in NASM assembly language. I have NASM 2.07 and Borland C++ compiler 5.0 (bcc32). My OS is Windows 7. I do not know how to do input and output with NASM in Windows platform. Please can you help me?

Comment: Your question suggests that you didn't do any research before asking it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to call the Win32 functions, accessible by linking the kernel32 libs (IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "C" functions "printf" and "scanf".
For doing that you need to declare it as "extern".
There is a simple example:

```
section .data
    input_string   db 0
    format         db "%s", 0
    output_string1 db "type something", 10, 0 ; "type something\n"
    output_string2 db "you wrote: %s", 0

extern _printf
extern _scanf

section .text
global _main
_main:                  ; int main()

    push output_string1 ;
    call _printf        ; printf(string1);
    add  esp, 4         ;

    push output_string1 ;
    push format         ;
    call _scanf         ; scanf(format, string1);
    add  esp, 8         ;


    push input_string   ;
    push output_string2 ;
    call _printf        ; printf(output_string2, input_string);
    add  esp, 8         ;

    xor  eax, eax       ; return 0;
    ret                 ;
```